# <lightning:navigation> for custom component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I have done google many times for using lightning:navigation to use for custom component but got only for standard component how can I do for custom component using javascript controller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `pageReference` to navigate to a custom component as below. Though the `type` mentions `standard__component`, the same type is applicable for any custom component as well.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) of `pageReference` for details.

> The Lightning component name in the format namespace__componentName

```
{    
    "type": "standard__component",
    "attributes": {
        "componentName": "c__MyLightningComponent" // replace c with namespace if applicable   
    },    
    "state": {
        "myAttr": "attrValue"    
    }
}
```